# Redirect Qemu console to a file or the host terminal?

Tags: logging, qemu

#### Background:

My system is an x86-based kernel and [ramfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_drive_software#Tmpfs_and_ramfs)-based root filesystem. I have made the ramfs-based on the cpio archive (which will use boot=/dev/ram0 as the RAM device), and I am having some issues with the init. The whole intention is to optimise the ramfs to the minimum to fit in a really small system. I am trying to debug the problem in the init. I start [QEMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU) in [Ubuntu 12.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.10_.28Quantal_Quetzal.29) (Quantal Quetzal) using the command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel linux-3.9.2/arch/x86/boot/bzImage -serial stdio \
    -append "root=/dev/ram0 console=tty1"
```

And as expected the system goes to OOPS.

#### Question:

I would like to see the logs to investigate the reason for the crash, but I cannot navigate in the QEMU console using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and <kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd>. So I tried redirecting the output to the host terminal using curses by the command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel linux-3.9.2/arch/x86/boot/bzImage -serial stdio \
    -append "root=/dev/ram0 console=tty1" -curses
```

But here again I am unable to navigate and find the problem.

P.S. If my system boots fine (using the correct rootfs) then I am able to navigate and see the messages.

How do I redirect the messages to the terminal or to a file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add the below command: `console=ttyAMA0 console=ttyS0`

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel linux-3.9.2/arch/x86/boot/bzImage -serial stdio \
    -append "root=/dev/ram0 console=ttyAMA0 console=ttyS0"
```

Now all dmesg logs will be redirected to your console.

One more thing: I observed from above command, where is your initial RAM disk? i.e - `-initrd (initrdimage)`

To boot the system you need two images, 1) zImage or bZimage (in case of x86)
2) rootfs -root file system

The missing component is rootfs in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot it work perfect i missed an option -initrd fs/mydisk which was my rootfs

Comment: If you add this command output log will come on both qemu and your terminal ."console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty mem=256M highres=off console=ttyS0"

Comment: I see a problem the printk's with KERN_DEBUG is not being displayed on any of the terminals. I had to change them to KERN_INFO. My debug log level is 7. I have changed it when i configured the kernel. Can anybody kindly please tell me is this prints getting buffered to any other terminal?

Comment: How do we create the initrd file to boot.

Comment: @ps06756  use busybox for creating initrd which contain minimal rootfile system have look @ this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409516/how-to-compile-busybox/22475170#22475170

Comment: How do I exit from the machine in qemu?

Comment: @everlof `<Ctrl-a x>`  will  Exit emulator

Comment: How can we print "hello world" for NIOS2. I am using "qemu-system-nios2 -nographic -kernel hello.out"

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can use the option -nographic and qemu-system will print direct to your console

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 [your things here] -nographic
```