# How to compile Busybox?

Tags: android, compilation, cross-compiling, busybox, instructions

(The i9100 and i9100p phones have Exynos 4210 SoC which includes Cortex A9 dual core 1.2Ghz processor which supports NEON.)

I will compile the latest busybox source snapshot available and upload it for everyone for free on internet and maybe even make my own free `BusyboxInstaller.apk` (I already downloaded today's 14th March snapshot from the official website) **because so many busybox installers have very outdated versions and I want to take advantage of possible optimizations for the Cortex A9 cpu.**

(NEON technology is a 128-bit SIMD (Single Instruction, Multiple Data) architecture extension.

*It can can accelerate multimedia and signal processing algorithms such as video encode/decode, 2D/3D graphics, gaming, audio and speech processing, image processing, telephony, and sound synthesis.*)

**1**  **does *such as* mean it will also benefit my busybox?**

**2** What other **instructions**/anythingelse I can use to optimize for i9100 devices?

**3** Can I compile on my phone instead of PC with only `1x2Ghz and 2GB RAM`? I think it should be much quicker because it has `2x1.5GHz and 1GB RAM` (I overclock only a bit) versus 1x2GHz, am I right?

> **4 How to compile busybox?**

What are these options for?

```
Force NOMMU build
Additional CFLAGS
Additional LDFLAGS
Additional LDLIBS
all in general configuration and Busybox Library Tuning and debug (I googled for each for a few hours but nothing satisfactory)
```

What kind of applet links to install?

(./_install) BusyBox installation prefix

**I have eeror when following vinayhunachyai instructions.

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- install
/home/euphoria/Sourcery/busybox/scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 11: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found
  CC      applets/applets.o
/bin/sh: 1: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found
scripts/Makefile.build:197: recipe for target 'applets/applets.o' failed
make[1]: *** [applets/applets.o] Error 127
Makefile:372: recipe for target 'applets_dir' failed
make: *** [applets_dir] Error 2
```

Comment: what applets can i safely disable?

Answer (score 5):

> How to compile busybox?

1st download toolchain. You can refer to this: [Advice regarding installing ARM toolchain on Ubuntu VM (64bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22266586/advice-regarding-installing-arm-toolchain-on-ubuntu-vm-64bit/22266762#22266762)

1. untar new source-code
2. create default config

`make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- defconfig`

A default configuration file is created.

3. update config to change it to our needs:

`make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- menuconfig`

The option to compile Busybox as a static executable, so that we don’t have to copy the dynamic libraries inside the root filesystem. The setting can be found in “Busybox Settings --> Build Options“.
Also, select what utilities you want embedded in Busybox.

4. Then, the following command builds Busybox and creates a directory called _install containing the root filesystem tree:

   `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- install.`

Compile statically. If you compile dynamically then you need to copy libraries to target.

For more details see this link: http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/busybox-for-arm-on-qemu/

Comment: @vinayhunchyai Im sorry I didnt see this earlier.When I run command 1) I get arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc not found.Should I be concerned? ALso  Im checking out each option in the busybox configuration and I couldnt find satisfactory information what they are for: please see my edited question

Comment: @vinayhunachyai please help with busybox options.(I would vote you up but it requires 15 reputation)

Comment: @vinayhunachyai I get erro at step 3: make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- install
/home/euphoria/Sourcery/busybox/scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 11: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found
  CC      applets/applets.o
/bin/sh: 1: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found
scripts/Makefile.build:197: recipe for target 'applets/applets.o' failed
make[1]: *** [applets/applets.o] Error 127
Makefile:372: recipe for target 'applets_dir' failed
make: *** [applets_dir] Error 2

Comment: do u have cross-toolchain ? if not download it https://sourcery.mentor.com/GNUToolchain/ 1st, the error is due to missing of toolchain gcc

Comment: @vinayhunachyai I dnt download this because it requires registration and is commercial so I downloaded gnu toolchain in parts (compiled bison and all the rest successfully) and I get the same error as before. **Does it have to be gnu toolchain from the website you provided?**

Comment: i dont know which toolchain r u using , So my suggestion is download lite version with your gmail account ,its free just u need to give your email id they ll send link to gmail

Comment: @vinayhunachyai I want to understand this better.I went to en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_toolchain and there is for example bison listed so I searched each tool lsted there (like bison) from official gnu download (like http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bison/) and compiled it.Ive done that with every tool listed there except the ones I already had (like Make) and checked in terminal if they work (by typing in for example bison)So now I have every tool listed there working.I want to avoid installing any more if possible  because my disk space is running out.So what is wrong with what I've described above???

Comment: is you intense is to compile busybox for ARM rite ??

Comment: @vinayhunachyai yes my intention is to copmile for arm, specifically for Galaxy S2

Comment: Then pls follow the above as i told ,to achive your goal. Once u compiled it take busybox exe. copy to target and execute it.

Comment: @vinayhunachyai But can I compile busybox after what I've done yesterday? (see comment above)

Comment: I got error `include/platform.h:152:23: fatal error: byteswap.h: No such file or directory
 # include <byteswap.h>
` any help please

Comment: After all of these, where should we put busybox binary file in android source code, to have it on output.zip?

Answer (score 0):

For Android you can use config [android_defconfig](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/configs/android_defconfig) and build with [examples/android-build](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/examples/android-build).

I successfully used **[busybox patched by sherpya](https://github.com/sherpya/android-busybox)**: his config [sherpya_android_defconfig](https://github.com/sherpya/android-busybox/blob/master/configs/sherpya_android_defconfig) and slightly modified build script [examples/android-build](https://github.com/sherpya/android-busybox/blob/master/examples/android-build).