# QEMU: How To mount rootfs using NFS on qemu emulator

Tags: linux, embedded, qemu

[image: qemu error snap] - **I build rootfs using busybox ,zimage using kernel source code.    now i want to use NFS to read rootfs on qemu prompt    can anybody
   tell me for arm as target and x86 as host machine.**

Answer (score 4):

1)Install nfs-kernel-server

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
```

2)create nfs folder where rootfs will be copied.

```
mkdir -p /srv/nfs/
chown 1000:1000 /srv/nfs
```

3)edit the file /etc/exports

`/srv/nfs 127.0.0.1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash,insecure,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)`

`or`if above does not  works then try this

`/srv/nfs 127.0.0.1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,insecure)`

4)Run the command as root

`exportfs -av`

Copy the _install directory that is generated with Busybox build into the NFS share.

5)If you are not created rootfs properly follow this post for complete details `http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/04/27/linux-nfs-root-under-qemu-arm-emulator/`

6)run

`qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel zImage -append "root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=10.0.2.2:/srv/nfs/_install rw ip=10.0.2.15::10.0.2.1:255.255.255.0 init=/sbin/init"`

Comment: thanks for your answer but i am getting error,i am not able to start /sbin/init process,also i edited my question(added snapshot of error) only for you ,i tried according to your answer,please replay.

Comment: Did u compiled busybox statically or dynamically? pls refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409516/how-to-compile-busybox/22475170#22475170

Comment: Vinod, the "/sbin/init" error means that your rootfs (created from busybox) does not have it, how about trying /bin/init?   (just mount it and try searching for the file first).