# Why is the linux kernel panicking?

Tags: linux, build, linux-kernel, qemu

I have downloaded the source of linux kernel 2.6 and built it with the default configuration. I am testing it on qemu-system-x86_64 with the following command :-

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -smp 4 -kernel arch/x86/boot/bzImage -initrd initramfs.gz -append "rdinit=/ root=/dev/ram" -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/ram0 console=ttyAMA0  console=ttyS0"
```

and, it is showing the following error when it tries to boot :-

```
     end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

with the stack trace being the following :-

```
9.187305] Call Trace:
[    9.187305]  [<ffffffff81ef0503>] mount_block_root+0x190/0x224
[    9.187305]  [<ffffffff81ef0688>] mount_root+0xf1/0xfc
[    9.187305]  [<ffffffff81ef07d0>] prepare_namespace+0x13d/0x176
[    9.187305]  [<ffffffff81ef022a>] kernel_init_freeable+0x1e2/0x1f2
[    9.187305]  [<ffffffff81eef8f3>] ? initcall_blacklist+0xad/0xad
[    9.187305]  [<ffffffff818098d0>] ? rest_init+0x80/0x80
[    9.187305]  [<ffffffff818098d9>] kernel_init+0x9/0xf0
[    9.187305]  [<ffffffff81819dac>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
[    9.187305]  [<ffffffff818098d0>] ? rest_init+0x80/0x80
```

I have been searching more about this error but, am not able to identify the cause of this error.
Can anybody please explain it to me why am I getting this error ? How can I resolve it ?

Please bear in mind that I have just started kernel development and still a noob in this area.

Comment: Are you using initrd or initramfs? The command line seems to reference both

Comment: I am using initramfs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098455/redirect-qemu-console-to-a-file-or-the-host-terminal/18100781#18100781 try this