# redirect QEMU window output to terminal running qemu

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, qemu

Im trying to debug the boot sequence of a linux kernel with qemu,
the command i'm running is:

```
  qemu -serial stdio -kernel <path to kernel> -hda <path to rootfs> -append "root=/dev/sda terminal = ttyS0"
```

During boot all the kernel messages are printed to the QEMU window.
Only when the boot has finished i get my prompt back to the terminal i ran QEMU in.

Now i can start using the kernel terminal I'm running and seeing the output in the terminal and not in QEMU window.

How do i get all messages including the boot messages to my terminal and not to QEMU window (because i cant scroll up in that window..) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098455/redirect-qemu-console-to-a-file-or-the-host-terminal/18100781#18100781

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use qemu to run a non-gui OS on the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710555/how-to-use-qemu-to-run-a-non-gui-os-on-the-terminal)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

1. remove `-serial stdio` parameter
2. add `-nographic` parameter
3. and change the kernel parameter `terminal = ttyS0` to `console=ttyS0`. This should do the trick.

`qemu -nographic -kernel ./bzImage -hda ./image.hda -append root=/dev/sda console=ttyS0`

You may want to check the script I use for kernel development: https://github.com/arapov/wrap-qemukvm (it's not very "production", but you can find useful `qemu` `cli` parameters there)

Comment: Some emulated machines will need `console=ttyAMA0,115200` rather than `console=ttyS0`.  Or you can just provide both as in vinay's answer.

Comment: Just check whether you want to set root=/dev/sda1 or /dev/sda . I had to set it to /dev/sda1

Comment: BTW, I've created a Buildroot version of your script: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat

Comment: After doing so, you might also want to automatically resize the serial console: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283206/92541

Comment: Doesn't work while booting from an ISO file. It complains `-append only allowed with -kernel option`

Answer (score 11):

refer this [Redirect Qemu console to a file or the host terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098455/redirect-qemu-console-to-a-file-or-the-host-terminal/18100781#18100781)
 to get the log on both  qemu and your terminal .use 
`"console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty  highres=off console=ttyS0"`

Comment: It is not the solution for my trivial problem, the second tty console disappeared in qemu: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/56302/qemu-2-7-0-for-the-raspi2-machine-do-not-show-the-second-tty-console-only-the

Comment: @42n4  https://learningfromyoublog.wordpress.com/ or https://learningfromyoublog.wordpress.com/2016/04/05/131/

Comment: I used the qemu machine raspi2 and cpu arm1176 and compiled with armv7a-hardfloat the original raspberry kernel sources with bcm2709_defconfig, so all was very "native" and it is vary sad it is not working at once, look at my question makefile: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/56302/qemu-2-7-0-for-the-raspi2-machine-do-not-show-the-second-tty-console-only-the

Answer (score 3):

Redirecting Qemu output to terminal might cause some problem (personally i don't like it). You can using options like `-noframe` (this will create new window but won't any window frame) or `-curses` to experience qemu output on terminal.