# How to boot FreeBSD image under Qemu

Tags: freebsd, qemu

I have a FreeBSD image that contains /boot/loader* and /boot/kernel and more. It boots fine under an EC2 instance but I would like to boot it with Qemu. I have tried various methods, but they have not worked. See below.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel kernel -nographic -append 'console=ttyS0' disk.img
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel loader -nographic -append disk.img
```

Comment: error message? output from file(1)?

Comment: no output or error. It just hangs.

Comment: Just have no idea how to start it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FreeBSD wiki has some recipes how to run FreeBSD inside Qemu

https://wiki.freebsd.org/QemuRecipes

Answer (score 7):

This boots on Ubuntu 20.04 amd64 host, QEMU 4.2.1:

```
wget https://download.freebsd.org/ftp/releases/VM-IMAGES/12.1-RELEASE/amd64/Latest/FreeBSD-12.1-RELEASE-amd64.qcow2.xz
unxz FreeBSD-12.1-RELEASE-amd64.qcow2.xz
sudo apt install qemu-system-x86
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive file=FreeBSD-12.1-RELEASE-amd64.qcow2,format=qcow2 -enable-kvm
```

The username is `root` with empty password:

[image]

[image]

The download page for that image is: https://www.freebsd.org/where.html

Unfortunately, trying to add:

```
-serial mon:stdio -nographic
```

[to get rid of the GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710555/how-to-use-qemu-to-run-a-non-gui-os-on-the-terminal) only shows the bootloader images on the terminal, but not the rest of boot. https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-hackers/2005-March/011051.html mentions how to fix that by modifying the image, which is annoying, but worked. On the GUI boot, I did:

```
echo 'console="comconsole"' > /boot/loader.conf
```

and then the next nographic boot worked fully on my terminal.

You can quit QEMU `-nographic` with `Ctrl-A X` as shown at: https://superuser.com/questions/1087859/how-to-quit-the-qemu-monitor-when-not-using-a-gui/1211516#1211516

The next issue is that the disk is full, I have to learn to increase its size. From interactive `df -Th` inspection, the image appears to contain a single raw [UFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_File_System) partition. I tried:

```
qemu-img resize FreeBSD-12.1-RELEASE-amd64.qcow2 +1G
```

but that is not enough presumably because the partition itself was not resized to fit the disk. Likely this can be achieved with `gpart` as shown at: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/disks-growing.html but I don't have the patience right now.

Comment: The last link (disk-growing) is obsoleted, [here](https://people.freebsd.org/~rodrigc/doc/handbook/disks-growing.html) is the new place.

Comment: For those who failed to grow the disk with command in the end: `growfs /dev/<target partition>`. The reply [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/freebsd-growfs-operation-not-permitted-aka-enlarge-your-partition) may help. TL;DR, run command `service growfs onestart` instead. Nevertheless, on my machine, part of the output says `gpart: arg0 'gpt/rootfs': Invalid argument`, but the partition was successfully resized though.